# bash script to change text into html

Tags: bash

Hello
I need to write a bash script that changes text in a file (txt, odt, doc etc) into primitive html code. It should change:

empty lines into paragraphs (< p> < /p>) 
   underlined text into headers (< h> that text < /h>

can anybody help me, please? 
thank you in advance

Comment: Why does it have to be a bash script? How about using Perl, for example? That should be easier...

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work and you would like to ask about?

Comment: Note that `<h>` is not a valid HTML tag, `<h1>` through `<h6>` are. Also, how do you underline text in a pure text file? (btw there's `catdoc` to convert DOC files to text)

Comment: pearl is not an option as i don't know it and wouldn't be able to explain. <br>

i tried reading line by line and checking if the line is empty and if it is it should replace it with paragraph tag. but i have no idea how to check if the line in a .doc or .odt is underlined (boldened, etc) <br>

Comment: You should find utilities to convert `.doc` and `.odt` files by asking a question on Super User.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson .odt is open format and do not need special utility to be opened. Practically it is a zip file with some xml-s.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a openoffice macro which will be afterwards called via command-line similarly as in for instance
http://itnewsworld.blogspot.com/2008/01/converting-office-to-openoffice-batch.html
By this way, you can process and produce all formats which are supported by OpenOffice.

For instance:

```
filename="a.odt"

oowriter -invisible "macro:///Standard.ModuleName.MacroName(filename)"
```

Answer (score 0):

‏What you are describing is actually a lightweight markup language, and indeed a subset of several [existing markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language), such as [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), [reStructuredTest](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) and [Texy](http://texy.info/en/syntax).

Consider using one of the existing tools for converting one of these into html.

For example, on my openSUSE box:

*Installation:*

```
 sudo zypper install python-markdown
```

*input.txt:*

```
this is a title
---------------

Here is one paragraph,
that continues in the next line.

And this is a new paragraph,
because of a blank line.
```

*use:*

```
markdown input.txt
```

*output:*

```
<h2>this is a title</h2>
<p>Here is one paragraph,
that continues in the next line.</p>
<p>And this is a new paragraph,
because of a blank line.</p>
```